# Storing incomplete work with git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm just getting to the stage where something like git flow is going to come in very handy with my project but I'm a bit unsure as to how to swap between features when the feature I'm currently working on isn't quite done.

So if I have a project and I do

```
$ git flow feature start feature1
```

then do some work but not quite get it to the stage where I'm happy to commit it before I need to head off and work on another issue, what should I do with my work before I do

```
$ git flow feature start feature2
```

?

Is git stash the correct way to go? It doesn't quite seem to do what I want it to do and looks like it could get quite messy quite quickly. But I definitely don't want to commit my changes and it seems silly to have re-clone the entire repo in another directory so I can work on it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of the rationale for `git stash`!

That said, you could just create a commit, and then do `git reset --soft HEAD^` when you come back to it (which deletes the commit, but retains the changes in your working copy).

Comment: Ahah - this seems like a plan to me. I just have a feeling that all the stashes in the list might get unwieldy and confusing after a very short time so I'm a bit wary of using it. The git reset route seems a lot nicer to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To store the changes locally without pushing them to the remote repository i simply commit every time before switching the branch.
At the End before i push i will then squash all the relevant commits to a single one containing all the changes.

You can find a description for squashing commits right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Comment: The thing is, I don't always want to commit the changes - even locally - before I switch branches because it's often hard to figure out what I was doing or where I was up to when I switch back.

Comment: I quite often do incremental commits, and then using `git rebase` I will consolidate all the changes into a single, or several, logical commits.  Never be afraid to commit often and early, as you can easily rewrite the history of the branch with git.  **NOTE:** You would never rebase and force push on the develop or master branch, but in a feature or release branch, it's all good.